# Inner join inverse Php mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `master_domain_list` and `temporary_domain_list`. `master_domain_list` contains a list with columns for the email ID and domain name. `temporary_domain_list` also contains the `domain` column.

I want to filter `temporary_domain_list` to show all domain names which are not present in `master_domain_list`.

I tried the following code (inner join inverse) but it's giving the whole list of domains from `temporary_domain_list` without removing the domains in `master_domain_list`.

```
$result1=mysqli_query($cons, "
      SELECT domain 
      FROM temporary_domain_list 
      WHERE domain NOT IN  (SELECT domain 
      FROM master_domain_list)
      ");
```

Comment: Your query seems to be fine, what's your problem? Want to do it with `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: This query is giving the whole list of domains from email_temporary without filtering or comparing with email_master.

Comment: Actually this query does *filtering or comparing*, I think. You used `NOT IN`, which means it will give you domains in `temporary_domain_list` and not in `master_domain_list`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes , but this query is returning whole domain list present in temporary_domain_list which is already present in master_domain_list.

Comment: Just a minor .. in your post you name the table  email_master and email_temprary .. nut in code .. you name temprary_domain_list and mater_domain_list ... hope this is not the problem

Comment: The table name is: (a) master_domain_list and (b) temporary_domain_list

Comment: Your query works fine for me with two simple sample tables. You'll have to provide more detail such as a `CREATE TABLE` syntax for both tables and some sample data which doesn't work. Is it possible some of the domains contain leading spaces or are in some other way not identical?